# For the polynomial $P(z)=\sum_{n=1}^Na_nz^n$

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers

Consider the polynomial $\displaystyle P(z)=\sum_{n=1}^Na_nz^n$ , $1\le N<\infty$ , $a_n \in \Bbb R \setminus \{0\}.$ Then with $\Bbb D=\{w\in \Bbb C:|w|<1\}$ ,

(A) $P(\Bbb D)\subset \Bbb R$.

(B) $P(\Bbb D)$ is open.

(C) $P(\Bbb D)$ is closed.

(D) $P(\Bbb D)$ is bounded.

It is very clear that (A) is FALSE. But I'am unable to check the other options. Can I get any hint to prove or disprove the other options ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hints. As regards (d), we have that for $|z|<1$,
$$|P(z)|\leq \sum_{n=1}^N|a_n||z|^n\leq \sum_{n=1}^N|a_n|.$$
Moreover for (c), consider the case when $P(z)=z$.

For (b), do you know the [open mapping theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Open_mapping_theorem_(complex_analysis))?

Comment: I'm not getting the your point for option (C). How $p(z)=z$ works ?

Comment: With $P(z)=z$, $P(\Bbb D)=\Bbb D$ which is not closed. So (c) is false by counterexample.